# Create loop device for ext4 filesystem

Tags: mount, filesystem, loop-device

I created and formatted a file as an ext4 file system and I am trying to mount it as a loop device. Initially, there were no loopX entries in `/dev`, so I created one like this:

```
root:~# mknod -m640 /dev/loop0 b 7 0
root:~# chown root:disk /dev/loop0
```

The node was created:

```
root:~# ls -l /dev/loop0
brw-r----- 1 root disk 7, 0 Aug 26 14:32 /dev/loop0
```

If I try to bind the loop device to the file, an error occurs:

```
root:~# losetup /dev/loop0 /root/virtual.ext4
/dev/loop0: Operation not permitted
```

I tried to set the permissions to `o777`, but it does not solve the problem.

What could cause this problem, and how can I solve it?

Comment: Try `sudo chmod 660 /dev/loop0` ;

Comment: @ali76 Thank you for the suggestion, but it does not work. Note that I already tried to set the permissions to 777 to no avail.

Answer (score 4):

You are kind of going about this in the wrong order.

Try this:

First create the loop device:

`sudo losetup /dev/loop0 /root/virtual.ext4`

Second, create a mount point for the device, replacing `<newdir>` with an appropriate directory name

`sudo mkdir /mnt/<newdir>`

Thirdly, mount the device.  You will need to use appropriate options if you want to use this as a RW device.

`sudo mount /dev/loop0 /mnt/<newdir>`

Reverse the process to remove the device:

```
sudo umount /mnt/<newdir>
sudo rm -r /mnt/<newdir>
sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

*copied
 almost verbatim from http://www.walkernews.net/2007/07/01/create-linux-loopback-file-system-on-disk-file/*

Comment: The `losetup` command fails: `/dev/loop0: No such file or directory`.

Comment: I was incorrect in advising you to first  `rm /dev/loop0` - please re-create it with `sudo mknod -m660 /dev/loop0 b 7 0 && sudo chown root:disk /dev/loop0`

Comment: Seems like my VPS provider compiled the kernel without support for kernel modules, so I won't be able to use loop devices at all. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I got such an error: `losetup: /root/virtual.ext4: failed to set up loop device: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the problem is, my VPS provider compiled the kernel without module support, so I cannot use loop devices at all, and there does not seem to be a way to change this.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop /media/USER/DISK/linux.img /media/USER/YourDIR
```

or

```
sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop /YourLinux.img /YourUserCreatedDIRectory
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands as root:

1. Create the loop device

   ```
   losetup -fP /root/virtual.ext4
   ```
2. Find the loop device (e.g. `/dev/loop3`)

   ```
   losetup -a | grep /root/virtual.ext4
   ```
3. Create directory and mount the loopback filesystem

   ```
   mkdir -p /mnt/virtual
   mount -o loop /dev/loop3 /mnt/virtual
   ```
4. Check the size

   ```
   df -h /mnt/virtual
   ```
5. Detach the loopback filesystem and delete the directory

   ```
   umount /mnt/virtual
   rm -r /mnt/virtual
   ```
6. Delete the loop device

   ```
   losetup -d /dev/loop3
   ```